# Firebase Equals Query With List Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm getting all users of the app in a list but I want to show only the users that are existing phone contacts; so I have all phone numbers in a list and I want to query if they exist in the contact list but I can't find a way to do it. I want to make it work like the Whatsapp add message system. Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

```
void GetPeoples(){
    Users users = new Users();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>
            (
                    Users.class,
                    R.layout.users_display_layout,
                    UsersViewHolder.class,
                    allDatabaseUserreference.orderByChild("phone_number").equalTo(numbers.size())
            ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, final int position) {
                    //if(numbers.contains(model.getPhone_number())){

                        viewHolder.setUser_name(model.getUser_name());
                        viewHolder.setUser_status(model.getUser_status());
                        viewHolder.setUser_thumb_image(getApplicationContext(), model.getUser_thumb_image());

                        viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(UsersActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                                profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", visit_user_id);
                                startActivity(profileIntent);
                            }
                        });
                    //} else {

                    //}
            }
    };
    usersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

////New Code I think I solved but I will test performance.

```
void GetPeoples(){
    Users users = new Users();
    for(int i =0 ;i<numbers.size();i++){
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>
                (
                        Users.class,
                        R.layout.users_display_layout,
                        UsersViewHolder.class,
                        allDatabaseUserreference.orderByChild("phone_number").equalTo(numbers.get(i))
                ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, final int position) {

                viewHolder.setUser_name(model.getUser_name());
                viewHolder.setUser_status(model.getUser_status());
                viewHolder.setUser_thumb_image(getApplicationContext(), model.getUser_thumb_image());

                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(UsersActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", visit_user_id);
                        startActivity(profileIntent);
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        usersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Comment: WHat is happening when you are using this code?

Comment: I see all members in app, but I want to see members if added to contact, I think I solved it but I dont know Is it a good way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    this is my code ..if any help to this code so use .thank You

   package com.example.cloudanalogy.CloudChat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.flags.Flag;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {



    private RecyclerView mConvList;

    private DatabaseReference mConvDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMessageDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter friendsRecyclerViewAdapter;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private String mCurrent_user_id;

    private View mMainView;
    String data;


    public ChatsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

        mConvList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.conv_list);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        Log.i("mCurrent_user_id",mCurrent_user_id);

        mConvDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat").child(mCurrent_user_id);

        mConvDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
        mMessageDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages").child(mCurrent_user_id);
        mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        mConvList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mConvList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        fatchChatRecord();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return mMainView;


    }
//------------------------OnStart method-------------------------------------


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        friendsRecyclerViewAdapter.startListening();



    }


    public void fatchChatRecord()
    {
        Query conversationQuery=mConvDatabase.orderByChild("timestamp");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Conv> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Conv>()
                .setQuery(conversationQuery, Conv.class)
                .build();


        friendsRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Conv, ConvViewHolder>((options)) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ConvViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, parent, false);


                return new ConvViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ConvViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Conv model) {

                final String list_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                Query lastMessageQuery = mMessageDatabase.child(list_user_id).limitToLast(1);

                lastMessageQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                        data = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();

                        holder.setMessage(data, model.isSeen());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb image").getValue().toString();

                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("online")) {

                            String userOnline = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();
                            holder.setUserOnline(userOnline);

                        }

                        holder.setName(userName);
                        holder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());

                        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {


                                Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                chatIntent.putExtra("id", list_user_id);
                                chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                                startActivity(chatIntent);

                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });





            }
        };

        mConvList.setAdapter(friendsRecyclerViewAdapter);

    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------ConvViewHolder----------------
    class ConvViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public ConvViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setMessage(String message, boolean isSeen){

            TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
            userStatusView.setText(message);

            if(!isSeen){
                userStatusView.setTypeface(userStatusView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            } else {
                userStatusView.setTypeface(userStatusView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
            }

        }

        public void setName(String name){

            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
            userNameView.setText(name);

        }

        public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx){

            CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
            Picasso.get().load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(userImageView);

        }

        public void setUserOnline(String online_status) {

            ImageView userOnlineView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_online_icon);

            if(online_status.equals("true")){

                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Thank You but I cant see any code of make query with contact. Did you make it ? Now I can see all users of my app but I want to show only users if added to my phone contact like Whatsaapp.